# What is a Hyper-Sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am interesting about the geometric properties of 3-D spheres and I know nothing about hyper-spheres. Please can you describe me, what is a hyper-sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  hypersphere (or $n$-sphere) is the set of points in $n$-dimensional space such that the distance from the point to the origin is constant:
$$
\{ x \in \mathbb R^n : | x | = c \}
$$for some constant $c$.
The most common use of the word refers to the $n = 4$ case.

Comment: There is some more information here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html

Comment: Why special on n=4 case?

Comment: Just because that is one more dimension then we have in our universe.  It is the first "weird" dimension, when we can no longer have a true mental picture of it.  Similar to a "hypercube" in four dimensions; note that the picture here cannot possibly be four dimensional, and yet it tries to represent a four dimensional shape:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube